# Flutter ios release build failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, flutter

### Steps to Reproduce

Run `flutter build ios`

I am having trouble with generating my release build for ios, I noticed after my app was rejected by the Apple team with the following:

`TMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in Frameworks/Flutter.framework/Flutter: _ptrace. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/`

I look it up about those APIs and it appears to have sent a debug build not the release one, so I run the command on the terminal for the release build and I got this:

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Building Dart code...                                    96,2s
 ├─Generating dSYM file...                                   0,4s
 ├─Stripping debug symbols...                                0,1s
 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           2,7s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         6,5s
Xcode build done.                                           109,5s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled,
    and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated. Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled,
    and then disable inference by changing the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" build setting to "Default" for the "Runner" target.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...          
    Building App.framework for arm64...

    Building App.framework for armv7...
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...             91,0s
    Built to build/aot/.
    warning: parsing line table prologue at offset 0x6f697463 found unsupported version 0x00
    warning: line table parameters mismatch. Cannot emit.
    note: while processing /Users/devel/FlutterProjects/ds_token/build/aot/armv7/snapshot_assembly.o
    Project /Users/devel/FlutterProjects/ds_token built and packaged successfully.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
    Non-fat binary /Users/devel/FlutterProjects/ds_token/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/barcode_scan.framework/barcode_scan is not armv7. Running lipo -info:
    Non-fat file: /Users/devel/FlutterProjects/ds_token/build/ios/Release-iphoneos/Runner.app/Frameworks/barcode_scan.framework/barcode_scan is architecture: arm64
    Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Just checking a few steps. First open the runner.xcworkspace and select the runner project (above the target), go to the product menu and select "clean build folder" next to the play button (or through the product menu), after the "runner" select the scheme "generic ios device" and then in the product menu the option "archive"

Comment: I think the problem is your flutter SDK is needed to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your replies, I solved it by uninstall flutter's SDK and reinstalling it again. And that solved the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved with 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37850#issuecomment-544309050
and signing review.