# flutter build ios hava some problems library not found for -lBSGridCollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, flutter

Build ios have some error

T.T

Xcode's output:
↳
    url_launcher-fgttqlawlkztnfglsqslrmrivxkq
    Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...
    Building App.framework for arm64...

```
Building App.framework for armv7...
Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...             38.2s
Built to build/aot/.
warning: parsing line table prologue at offset 0x6f697463 found unsupported
version 0x00
warning: line table parameters mismatch. Cannot emit.
note: while processing
/Users/a./Desktop/business-b/business-b/build/aot/armv7/snapshot_assembly.o
Project /Users/a./Desktop/business-b/business-b/ios/.. built and packaged
successfully.
ld: library not found for -lBSGridCollectionViewLayout
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
invocation)
url_launcher-fgttqlawlkztnfglsqslrmrivxkq
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build
description
```

Comment: Try changing the workspace settings to Legacy build system, `Xcode -> File -> Workspace Settings -> Build Systems` change from `New Build System(default) -> Legacy Build System`

Answer (score 0):

In this link [Flutter ios release build failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58086795/flutter-ios-release-build-failed-with-exit-code-1) I found a reference to reinstall Flutter SDK, but it didn't work for me.